# how can i get driver for Acer V5 571-g laptop ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, drivers, laptop, acer

I made **lshw** on my laptop and become this:

```
id: 
serial
description:    SMBus
product:    7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id:    
1f.3
bus info:   
pci@0000:00:1f.3
version:    04
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
configuration:  
latency =   0
resources:  
memory  :   f3b14000-f3b140ff
ioport  :   efa0(size=32)
```

that means that no driver was installed for this device, right?
I don't know how to get the driver and how to install.

Any advices for the newbie?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMBus controllers do not have installable drivers. Not having a driver for an SMBus controller should not cause any issues - they are rarely used in practice. If you have correct battery readings in the power manager and the hotkeys work, you can ignore it.

Comment: okay, thanks! But here is another problem, I thought that lack of SMBus driver might create error on startup - here: kernel: [    1.842751] usb 1-1.4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22 - don't know where to watch and how to investigate this problem